# #if DEBUG and Conditional(“DEBUG”) called in Release build

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have a method that sets up some Debug only configurations, I have used this pattern on a few projects and with some of them it seems that nor ***#if DEBUG*** nor ***Conditional("DEBUG")*** are omitted in my release build.

**Any ideas why?**

Define DEBUG constant is checked:
[image]

Comment: Well that's _because_ "Define DEBUG constant" is checked. You need to uncheck it.

Comment: @crazy_p, Would you please share the latest information about this issue? Do you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that may be obvious for some: the Build configuration changes based on the selected Configuration (eg. Debug) and Platform (eg. Any CPU).

In order to have ***#if DEBUG*** and ***Conditional("DEBUG")*** working as expected, the DEBUG constant must be defined in the *'Debug' configuration only*!

Notice the difference:

Debug:
[image]

Release:
[image]

If DEBUG is defined in Release, when using ***#if DEBUG*** or ***Conditional("DEBUG")***, the condition will return true because the DEBUG constant exists in the project configuration.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @Evk, ""Define DEBUG constant" is checked. You need to uncheck it".

That defines DEBUG for the preprocessor even if it is not in the text box above it